# Let new user choose password on first login attempt

Tags: login, password

I know that fedora has this feature when creating a new account, you can set it so that when the user logs into their new account, they can choose the password themselves.

How is this achievable in Ubuntu and why is the option not there? They both use the same accounts GUI application to my knowing. Why has Ubuntu stripped that feature out of it?

EDIT: This questions is here to actually know the reason behind this kind of change in Ubuntu's Accounts GUI program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force the user to change their password at first login](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30114/force-the-user-to-change-their-password-at-first-login)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity doesn't have this option:

[image]

To set this up on unity, use this command:

```
chage -d 0 <user-name>
```

(note that's `chage` not `change`)

Then the user sees this:

[image]

---

I can on GNOME. Go to [system settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRjfF.png), and click User Accounts. Add new account, and click on that user.

[image]

Click on `Account Disabled`, next to Password

[image]

Click "Set a password now", and chose "To be set at next login". Then click Change.

[image]

Comment: Thank, I wonder why Unity decided to strip it out tough. A really useful feature that is.

Comment: @Kaspar yeah, strange. Security? So people couldn't login first and change it - not sure.

Comment: I don't think unity removed it. I think gnome added it.